# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();; FileSource[hdfs://localhost:9000..]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to join the csv sink stream with rate sink stream:

```
spark2.readStream
      .format("csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .csv("hdfs://"+hdfsLocation+"/generator/"+shortPath)
      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

and

```
val rate = spark.readStream
  .format("rate")
  .option("rowsPerSecond", 1)
  .option("numPartitions", 10)
  .load()
```

with

```
   val cvsStream2 = 
   rate.as("counter").join(cvsStream.as("csv")).where("csv.id == 
   mod(counter.value," + divider + ")").withWatermark("timestamp", "1 
   seconds")
```

which is later called as

```
 dataFrame.select(
      lit(topicName) as "key",
      concat(date_format(col("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), lit(" : "), lit(digitalTwinId), lit(" : "), lit(new ColumnName(columnName))) as "value")
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .queryName("kafkaDataGenerator" + columnName)
      .start()
```

But I'm getting the exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
FileSource[hdfs://localhost:9000/generator/csv5922743056983510526/kikai.csv]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.$anonfun$checkForBatch$1(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.$anonfun$checkForBatch$1$adapted(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForBatch(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertSupported(QueryExecution.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$withCachedData$1(QueryExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.withCachedData(QueryExecution.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$optimizedPlan$1(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertOptimized(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.$anonfun$cacheQuery$2(CacheManager.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:3146)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.readFromCSVFile(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:63)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.readFromCSVFile$(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:21)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest$$anon$1.readFromCSVFile(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:19)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.generateStream(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:79)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.generateStream$(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:66)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest$$anon$1.generateStream(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:19)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.generateStream(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:151)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGenerator.generateStream$(KafkaDataGenerator.scala:138)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest$$anon$1.generateStream(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:19)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.$anonfun$new$1(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:30)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1682)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.org$scalamock$scalatest$AbstractMockFactory$$super$withFixture(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory.$anonfun$withFixture$1(AbstractMockFactory.scala:35)
    at org.scalamock.MockFactoryBase.withExpectations(MockFactoryBase.scala:51)
    at org.scalamock.MockFactoryBase.withExpectations$(MockFactoryBase.scala:43)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.withExpectations(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory.withFixture(AbstractMockFactory.scala:34)
    at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory.withFixture$(AbstractMockFactory.scala:31)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.withFixture(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1680)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTest$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1674)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:396)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.runTests$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1749)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1147)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1129)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike.run$(FlatSpecLike.scala:1793)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
    at org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll.run$(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:208)
    at io.sekai.core.streaming.KafkaDataGeneratorTest.run(KafkaDataGeneratorTest.scala:12)
    at org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner.run(JUnitRunner.scala:99)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

if I switch back from stream datatframe to batch dataframe, everything works fine:

```
spark2.read
      .format("csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .csv("hdfs://"+hdfsLocation+"/generator/"+shortPath)
      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

It's not clear for me, what kind of `Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();` is awaited, if 1) streaming dataframe is a readStream and can't provide writeStream.start to it; 2) batch dataframe can't also provide writeStream.start(). What was exactly wrong in csv streaming?

Unfortunately I can't ever print the physical plan for the execution, as the exception occurs before the DataFrame being created for the csv stream.

And it works with very bad performance if I remove the persistanc part:

```
spark2.readStream
  .format("csv")
  //.option("inferSchema", "true") //is it working?
  //.option("header", "true") //is it working?
  .schema(schema)
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .csv("hdfs://"+hdfsLocation+"/generator/"+shortPath)
//      .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Why persist makes it impossible to run as the stream dataframe and no persist makes it possible to be run only as a batch dataframe?

Comment: A CSV file or directory isn't a stream, so what did you want to happen with `readStream`?

Comment: because it surprisingly works, please see the last code snippet.

Comment: It's meant to be used for atomic file uploads, not for reading files that already exist

Comment: @OneCricketeer please add your explanation as the official answer to accept it